# Prevent Multiple Mouse Middle Click Events

Tags: mouse, xinput, events

For some weird reason, my mouse is sending `multiple middle click events` when I do a middle click at times. Happens once in a while - but not always. I'm fairly certain its a `hardware issue`.

Its a major annoyance as I paste using middle click a lot - and the same text get pasted 2-3 times.

I'm trying to get over the issue without having to buy another mouse.

> Is it possible to disable multiple middle click event if they happen in quick succession?
>
> xinput has a 'Evdev Middle Button Timeout' - but setting that to 1000 or so makes no difference.

Comment: I had the same in the past but the issue came and left randomly. As of today, it reappeared suddenly and can't do anything about it, restarting the machine and/or X doesn't do anything. Using Ikari Steelseries laser mouse on Gentoo Linux.

Comment: Gave up after trying a few things - bought a new mouse. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a physical issue with the mouse, one option is to quit using the 3rd wheel and remap your mouse such that a simultaneous click of the two buttons (left and right) is interpreted as a middle click. You can do so via `Section InputDevice` in your `xorg.conf` file. Change `Option Emulate3Buttons` to `yes` and play with the delay time on `Emulate3Timeout` to a comfortable setting. Full documentation is [here](ftp://www.x.org/pub/xorg/X11R6.7.0/doc/mouse5.html).